# How did Microsoft manage to auto-install "HP Smart" on my laptop (running Windows 10 LTSC without a store)?

Tags: windows-10

My laptop runs Windows 10 LTSC (21H2). I know this version isn't supposed to be used by ordinary consumers, but I've been bitten by the auto update before, so the last time I had to reinstall, I chose this version.

I didn't try to restore the Windows Store because I don't need it, and I've managed to completely disable Windows Update by denying permission to the SYSTEM account for specific registry paths. Everything was running smoothly until today, when I found a "pending" app appearing in my Start Menu called "HP Smart".

[image: HP Smart app appearing in Start Menu]

A quick Google search tells me that this is happening to others as well and is likely to be a bug, but what I care more is **how** Microsoft installed this app without my permission.

1. I'm running Windows 10 LTSC 2021, which doesn't have the Windows Store to begin with, and I didn't restore it manually (I guess that's why the app is stuck in a "pending" state instead of being installed).
2. Windows Update is completely disabled, I haven't received any updates since installing the OS last month. I know it's not a very good practice, but I've been bitten by auto updates before, so I choose not to have them at all.
3. The "automatically download manufacturers' apps..." setting is turned off (selected No).

Yet still, the "HP Smart" app appears out of nowhere in my Start Menu. How did Microsoft do this, and how can I prevent things like this from happening in the future? Giving up using Windows is not an option because of software compatibility.

Of course, I don't have any HP devices connected to the laptop or on the home network. I can remove it by using "uninstall" from right-click menu, but it will reappear after a reboot.

---

Update:

As I continued trying to figure this out today, I found that this is very likely to be related to a bug in which Windows incorrectly identifies all printers as "HP LaserJet M101-M106".

Although I don't have any printers, the built-in virtual printers like Fax, Microsoft Print to PDF and Microsoft XPS Document Writer are affected by this bug as well. However, the drivers are not updated. I tried to use Microsoft Print to PDF, and it works just fine. Other people on the Internet also report that their non-HP printers still work, despite being identified by Windows as HP printers.

So again, **how** did Microsoft manage to do that?

1. I don't have Windows Store
2. Windows Update is not running (completely disabled via registry permission edit)
3. I have turned off  "automatically download manufacturers' apps", yet Windows still tries to install "HP Smart" for me because it sees the three virtual printers as "HP LaserJet M101-M106"

Although I didn't check back then, I highly doubt the three virtual printers are incorrectly identified as HP printers from a fresh install, so this information MUST have come from the Internet through some Windows features, of which I'd like to know what they are and how to disable them.

---

Update 2:

Microsoft has released a [tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5034510-microsoft-printer-metadata-troubleshooter-tool-december-2023-b3197f24-fd25-430d-96d2-70f2044ce6a1) to resolve the printer rename issue and will remove the HP Smart app as well.

Although I didn't find any official statement about how this happened, it is very likely caused by the Windows Metadata and Internet Services (WMIS) feature, and it can be blocked with this group policy:

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Installation > Prevent device metadata retrieval from the Internet
```

However, by the description of this policy, it seems Windows should follow the "automatically download manufacturers' apps..." setting if this policy is not configured, so... I have no idea how it happened on my laptop, maybe it has something to do with me connecting a new monitor recently that triggered some kind of metadata download? I have enabled the policy now, but I'm not sure if it will be enough to prevent future shenanigans. Maybe I should just configure a hardware firewall to block some Microsoft domains.

Comment: The most likely explanation is it was accidentally included in a cumulative update.

Comment: Unless this is a company machine,  updates will restart at some point.  This is likely what happened

Comment: As you state, MS has installed *HP Smart* without user request or permission: https://www.ghacks.net/2023/11/30/microsoft-is-reportedly-auto-installing-the-hp-smart-app-on-windows-10-and-11-pcs/ . Perhaps this is done on machines allowing MS to perform third-party software updates? Perhaps this is Windows-as-a-service; MS is in control of the machine on your desk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCcdr4O-3gE & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2I7vPbthvWo